# React Native 0.63 not updating main.jsbundle after code changes

Tags: xcode, react-native

I installed the latest version of React 0.63.2 and using XCode v11.6 and I noticed a couple things:

1. main.jsbundle does not exist and you have to create it first before entering the Terminal command: npx react-native run-ios.
2. If you make any code changes, the main.jsbundle is not updated when you run the Terminal command: npx react-native run-ios.
3. Should you be running the XCode project in Debug mode or Release?

Has anyone seen these issues with .63.2?

Comment: have you found a solve? im crashing due to `h.Animated.Text.propType.styles`, commonly caused by the `react-native-material-textfield` pakcage, but i removed that pakcage and no longer use. the only instance of this comes from my main.jsbundle (rn v0.63.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the entire problem revolved around my hosts file. I had set uncomment my localhost and it finally worked. I had commented it out a long time ago for my Parallels VM.